# Set array value to a value from the same array on creation PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, assign

I'm trying to see if you can assign an array value during creation to a value in the same array.

If I'm declaring and initializing an array like this:

`$this->array = array(...);`

Can I do something like this?

`$this->array = array
                (
                    'value1' => 'hello',
                    'value2' => $this->array['value1'],
                );`

I've tried it already and I get back

`Notice: Undefined index: value1 in /Sites/website/config.php on line 329`

**I've gotten around this problem already but now out of interest I want to see if theres actually a way to do this.**

It has to be during creation and declared like above, not through

`$array['value1'] = 'foo';
$array['value2'] = $array['value1'];`

or

`$common = 'foo'; 
$array = array('value1' => $common, 'value2' => $common);`

Is this technically impossible or is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.  The array has to be parsed before it can be assigned, so at the time `$this->array['value1']` is being calculated, `$this->array` is still null.

Basically, `$this->array['value1']` cannot be be accessed before `$this->array['value2']` is set, which needs to access `$this->array['value1']`, which cannot be accessed before . . .

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting `Notice: Undefined index: value1 in /Sites/website/config.php on line 329` is because when you're defining your array the value you're trying to access has not yet been defined because you haven't reached the end of the initial function.

In the following code:

```
$this->array = array
                ( //this is the start of the array
                    'value1' => 'hello',
                    'value2' => $this->array['value1'],
                ); //this is the end of the array statement.
```

The array is not defined until you reach the end of the statement.

The reason the other methods work is because you're using multiple steps to access an already existing variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible, assign the element when the array starts
you can set as false and before the action that set the value as your code.

example :

```
$common = 'foo'; 
$array = array(
'value1' => $common, 
'value2' => $common
);
```

or you can use the function array_combine

Comment: Really appreciate your answer but I wasn't looking for workarounds to the problem as I'd already figured something out. Your example is letter for letter the exact same as I have posted above as one of my workarounds for the problem.